# MVC architecture in PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns, mvc

I have developed a few web applications according to my own coding style similar to MVC architecture. I'm a self learner. But there is no controller class or model class. In my way, I don't split the URL. I have mentioned below an example URL. Now I'm familiar with this process, but I know this is not a professional level coding, so I tried to move to MVC. Now I can easily manage any javascript, ajax call. I don't know how to use JavaScript and Ajax in MVC.

Basically my question is:  Shall I continue in this way?

My project file structure.

Below example based on [this URL](http://www.www.mysite.com/index.php?view=user/index&uid=234)

```
/root
  -/images
  -/include
  ---database.php
  ---user.php
  ---course.php
  -/layout
  ---/user
  ---/course
  ---index.php
  -index.php
  -config.php
```

**Cofig.php**

```
require("include/database.php");
require("include/user.php");
require("include/course.php");

$db = Database::getInstance();
$user = new user();
$course = new course();
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
include('config.php');

//get view page using url
$view_page = isset($_GET['view']) ? $_GET['view']: 'home';

?>
<html>
<body>   
   <div id='header'></div>
   <div id='content'>
      <?php
        include('layout/index.php');
      ?>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**layout/index.php**

```
<?php 
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/layout/'.$view_page.'.php');
?>
```

**layout/user/index.php**

```
//this page will be displayed : www.mysite.com/index.php?view=user/index&uid=234
// user/index = (folder/page) or (view/action)
// these details will be dispalyed with <div id='content'></div>

<?php

$userDetails = $user->getUserDetails($_GET['uid']);

  echo $userDetails['username'];
  echo $userDetails['email'];

?>
```

Comment: Regarding the last (removed) note: even if you get downvoted (which I doubt), you won't be blocked from asking questions as that system is not enabled on this site.

Comment: I can't see how this is MVC. Please have a look at [this user's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/727208/teresko) top answers on [so].

Answer (score 2):

### Code Review:

- **Naming Convention**: `$variableNames` and `functionNames()` should be in camelCase, `ClassNames` should be in CamelCaps. Keep this convention to make your code more readable!
- **Use an autoloader**: To stop you from being worried about loading classes, use an autoloader. See **[`spl_autoload_register()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)** for registering an autoloading function.
- **Don't use Singletons**: Do ***not*** use Singletons. Singletons are global, they introduce hidden dependencies to your code and make it unpredictable and untestable.
- **No explicit dependncies in sight**: What does your `user` object need in order to work? I'm guessing a database connection, maybe even a user_id? Why are you not passing those to the `user`'s constructor?

  ```
   $user = new User($db, $_SESSION["user_id"]); // For example
  ```

### How to improve

This code, contrary to popular belief, is **not MVC**. MVC stems from good OOP practices, and the separation of concerns. The idea is to separate your application into three major **layers**:

- The **Input**: The Controller layer.
- The **Output**: The View layer.
- The **Processing and Logic**: The Model layer.

Where each has its own job and responsibilities, its own set of objects, and its own role in the application.

I propose you start with learning about OOP, avoid PHP frameworks, and once you grasp OOP, start looking at MVC.